# Opening a Gmail message by URL when not logged into gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm creating a new draft email using the Java gmail api. This is all done and working fine, but there are some oddities when opening the created draft in the users browser that are proving annoying.

To view the new draft email, I'm using something like the following URL - 
https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=1234567890

This works fine if the user is already signed into gmail, it takes them to the drafts folder and opens the specified email for editing/sending. 
If they aren't signed in though, it shows the gmail login page, and after entering credentials, it drops the parameters and just goes to
https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox

Is there an alternative approach to ensure the parameters aren't lost (as I'm assuming there is no way to auto log in the user via oauth credentials, SSO, SAML or some other means?)

Comment: `gmail` is afraid someone else is logging in now who doesn't belong viewing that draft.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that. I tried adding the "authuser=xyz@gmail.com" parameter in the hope that might be checked against the user signing in to resolve that ambiguity, no joy though.